# How to change v-text-field width in Vuetify?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I placed v-text-field component inside a toolbar however it takes almost all available space.
How can I change the width of this text-field to take less space?

```
<v-toolbar
    dense
  >
    <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
    <v-toolbar-title>Title</v-toolbar-title>
    <v-text-field
      hide-details
      label="Filled"
      placeholder="Search"
      filled
      rounded
      dense
      single-line
      append-icon="mdi-magnify"
    ></v-text-field>
    <v-btn rounded>Button 1</v-btn>
    <v-btn icon>
      <v-icon></v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn icon>
      <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </v-toolbar>
```

Comment: I have usually solved this using the Vuetify [grid system](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/#grid-system), and placing `v-spacer`s where needed and specifying `cols="3"`, for instance, on the `v-col`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it by css in scoped style:

```
<style scoped>
/deep/ .v-text-field{
      width: 400px;
}
</style>
```

and for detailed information read [Vuetify documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields).

Comment: It worked, but how can you do it in HTML in inside the element itself without CSS? Especially if you've multiple inputs, and you want to add every input a specific width

Comment: add a class to each input in the HTML and then in CSS your desired width per class? I guess you can't do it without hacking the CSS, width is not exposed to v-text-field

Answer (score 24):

Since the toolbar is `display:flex` you could use `class="shrink"`...

```
      <v-text-field 
            hide-details 
            label="Filled" 
            placeholder="Search" 
            filled 
            rounded 
            dense 
            single-line 
            append-icon="mdi-magnify" class="shrink">
      </v-text-field>
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/h3Y8u3nK7P

Comment: This kind of works but then everything is stacked next to each other, is there a way to include some spacing or move those buttons and text field apart?

Comment: Yes, you can use the spacing utils.. for example `mx-4` on the textfield. I updated the demo: https://codeply.com/p/h3Y8u3nK7P

Comment: I used this answer to modify the exact width: class="shrink" style="width:100px".

Answer (score 6):

A Vuetify answer would be the following:
Wrap your `v-text-field` in a `v-responsive` like so:

```
<v-responsive class="ma-0 pa-0" :width="`${input.length}.5rem`">
   <v-text-field v-model="input"/>
</v-responsive>
```

You can of course change the width calculation to some arbitrary javascript, this way the text-field will always fit the typed input.

Answer (score -3):

i think you can use width="...px" in your v-text-field tag so:

```
<v-text-field
    ...

    width="...px"
    
    ...     
 ></v-text-field>
```